# Change the position of backstack fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Currently, I have a Fragment stack like this.

> F1 -> F2 -> F3 -> F4 -> F5

And in an activity, I have one button **B1**.

My question is when I press B1 button from the activity how can I update Fragment stack like below.

> F2 -> F3 -> F4 -> F5 -> F1.

I have used string tags at the time of addtobackstack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using Stack in your code. And in fragment transaction, you have to use add instead of replacing the fragment. On button B1 press you have to pop fragment F1 from the stack and again you have to push it to the stack. I thought it may be work for you.

Comment: I will try this in my code. It sounds like it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by this code:

```
public void fragmentInflater(Fragment newFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment oldFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(newFragment.getClass().getName());
    if (oldFragment == null) {
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment, newFragment.getClass().getName());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    } else {
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, oldFragment, newFragment.getClass().getName());
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Use this method for adding fragments to your container and you will achieve what you want. It will also prevents adding duplicated fragments to your container.